# Changing to CMake - one source, 48 DLLs

Tags: cmake

I maintain a C++ geometry library that is compiled in two different flavors from the same source code using #defines, namely for 2D/2.5D. These two flavors are compiled for Win32/x64 and as Debug/Release versions. Thus 8 DLLs are created for each of VS2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017. Currently I use a manually created Visual Studio solution: 
[image]

and Batch-Build. It works but I'd rather use CMake to compile the DLLs via command line. There is no need to create a solution for the Visual Studio IDE because the source code is developed under Linux.

Until now I'm rather a CMake user, thus I'd like to ask if the below outlined solution makes sense:

1. Create one CMakeLists.txt that contains two add_library calls, one for 2D and one for 2.5D. Using SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES it should be possible to pass different #defines.
2. The command "cmake -G "Visual Studio 11" -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .." should then for example create the two DLL flavors for VS2012/x64/Release.
3. It would need 24 such calls for VS 2008-2017, Debug/Release, Win32/x64 and I would put these into a script.

Q: Does the above make sense?

Q: How can the 24 calls to CMake be scripted when the shell or at least the environment variables must be changed to match the different compilers?

Q: Is it correct that Debug/Release, Win32/64 can't be specified inside CMakeLists.txt and thus it must be passed to the cmake command?

Just in case: The library is used in many projects and users really need  support for old compilers. Maybe not for VS2008 but VS2010 is still very popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the above make sense?

Yes.

> How can the 24 calls to CMake be scripted when the shell or at least the environment variables must be changed to match the different compilers?

Just one after another?

```
cmake -S . -B 17_64_R -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build 17_64_R --target all
cmake -S . -B 17_64_D -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cmake --build 17_64_D --target all
... and so on ...
cmake -S . -B 08_32_D -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" -A Win32 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cmake --build 08_32_D --target all
```

> Is it correct that Debug/Release, Win32/64 can't be specified inside CMakeLists.txt and thus it must be passed to the cmake command?

No, you can. It is correct that that information *shouldn't* be specified in cmake configuration. Cmake is a tool for *configuring* the build, so it will stay portable to different architectures. Why would you then decide to limit cmake to generate only one configuration, if the point of using cmake is to be portable? (Most common answer: to use cmake rich features to generate proper build system). It's not good practice. But you always can `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug") set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Visual Studio 17")` and sometimes you do, but only to test cmake configuration.

> one for 2D and one for 2.5D. Using SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES it should be possible to pass different #defines.

This would look strange. Just add to CMakeLists.txt:

```
  add_executable(final_executable ...)

  # then below
  if(${FLAVOR} STREQUAL "2D")
      target_compile_definitions(final_executable
           PUBLIC
              FLAVOR_2D=1
              SOME_OTHER_MACRO_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_SET="2D FLAVOR"
       )
       target_link_libraries(final_executable PUBLIC 2d_library)
       # ... and so on ...
  elif(${FLAVOR} STREQUAL "2.5D")
      target_compile_definitions(final_executable
           PUBLIC
              FLAVOR_2_5D=1
              SOME_OTHER_MACRO_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_SET="2.5D FLAVOR"
       )
       target_link_libraries(final_executable PUBLIC 2_5d_library)
  else()
      message(FATAL_ERROR "You must specify FLAVOR to be 2D or 2.5D")
  endif()
```

Then you configure the build system with:

```
  # for 2D configuration
  cmake ... -D FLAVOR="2D" ...
  # for 2.5D configuration
  cmake ... -D FLAVOR="2.5D" ...
```

There is no need for `set_target_properties` to use when setting macros. And you shouldn't do that really, there are cmake commands just for that. There are `target_compile_definitions`, `target_inlude_directories`, `target_link_libraries` and lastly on newest cmake `target_link_options` (which just was done with `target_link_libraries` on older versions). Even `target_sources` let's you add sources. Usually `set_target_properties` is used for advanced stuff, like interprocedural_optimization and such.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. The question regarding the script was:  When I compile for example a VS2012 x64 binary then I must do that in a VS2012 x64 Native Command Prompt while VS2015 requires another shell. AFAIK this is only a question of the environment variables. Are they changed automatically by CMake so that the shell does not matter or does the script need to change the environment before CMake is called?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the "environment" shoudn't matter. I think cmake generator automagically find paths to proper compiler versions. Matters what you put inside `cmake -D ....=...` variables. Cmake is there, to make the environment insignificant and to provide same builds across different "environments". So you should be able to use any "command prompt".